# Unhelpful-Title Warning for Question Writers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, title, quality-improvement

There are several questions that have meaningless titles, such as this one:

[image]

They commonly originate from users with very low reputation (often as a first post), and are downvoted.

I think it would save time for everyone, and be a more positive experience to the new posters, if while trying to post the question, there would be a warning that the title is too general to the point of being meaningless. It probably could be done using an NLP model trying to predict a downvoted answer from the title alone, but a low-effort rule-set could probably catch a lot of it:

1. Low rep user (or first post)
2. Title contains "help", "need", "someone", "aynone"
3. Title is composed of only English words, none of which are tags
4. Etc.

Having a downvoted first question is probably not a good experience, so it might pay to invest in things that seem easy to address.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perhaps a message like this?

[image: When I enter the exact title mentioned in the question as an example of a low-quality, non-descriptive title in the "Ask Question" page, I get the following warning message in a yellow box: "Many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements. Consider updating your question title and body to be more descriptive."]

Yeah, we have that already. Doesn't seem to be helping much, does it?

Comment: Somehow, knowing that this warning already exists is kind of depressing.

Comment: Numerous studies have shown that warning dialogs that come **without** an electric shock are not particularly effective.

Comment: Wait, @yivi, so the downvote button *isn't* connected to deliver an electric shock? Hmm, I thought it must be... What else would explain all the whining about it that I see??

Comment: I've seen this title before, mainly because I'm horrible at writing titles. I usually  want to get rid of that warning, and all I have to do to get rid of it is change one or two words. So that feature is pretty much useless.

Comment: @10Rep Perhaps, instead of subverting the system, you should learn to work *with* it? Look at other upvoted questions with good titles and try to learn from them. Study carefully any title edits that are made to your question by veteran users. Look for opportunities to discuss how to write good titles. Et cetera. I don't really think the argument that you've found a way to work around the system is an argument against it.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm trying to learn how to write a good title, but just wanted to point out that that feature is kinda useless.

Comment: @10Rep Yeah, I understood your meaning. I just disagree. I don't think you can declare a feature "useless" just because it is possible to trivially work around it. Most automated warnings can be trivially worked around. That isn't the point of them. If we wanted to block these questions entirely, we could certainly do so. The point is just to get people to reconsider. If you reconsider, but post anyway, that's on you: you've been warned to expect downvotes and/or a negative reception, so you can't complain about them when they come.

Comment: @CodyGray I think the current feature should disallow questions like that. Instead of simply a warning, it should be a block or something. That being said, I will work with the feature next time.

Comment: Shouldn't this warning be taken outside from the "Similar questions" popup? and appear inmediately below the title? That would bring the warning to user attention better. Currently OP might think that the warning is somehow related to the "similar questions" prompt, like "please check this similar questions yada yada" and not directly related to his question title

Comment: @MarcSances That's an interesting suggestion. Perhaps it would be a useful change. Consider posting that as a separate feature request.

Comment: @Code Gray Sometimes choosing a representative title for a question is not always easy, I suffer from dyslexia which means it's sometimes it very difficult to choose the right word or create a helpful title string. If you badly phrase a question you can down marked just for your choice of grammar, or people assume that you are a dumb user/beginner and therefore not worth helping