# Make the "many similar phrased questions have downvotes" banner prominent

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, design, asking-questions, user-experience

This is a follow-up feature request regarding [a comment I posted on "Unhelpful-Title Warning for Question Writers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403064/unhelpful-title-warning-for-question-writers#comment811534_403065).

As shown in the following picture, when a user attempts to beg for help in the question title, a banner appears to warn him that "many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements".

[image: Stack Overflow Ask a Question wizard, showing "many similarly phrased questions have received feedback like downvotes or requests for improvements" banner inside a "Similar Questions" box]

This is a perfect way to hint a user on improving his question, however, the placement is a little odd, since the banner is shown inside the "Similar questions" box, which can be collapsed, further hiding the banner from the user.

Given that the banner content is in no way related to the "similar questions" context, I suggest moving this banner outside that box, giving it more visibility right below the title, like this:

[image: Suggestion of improvement]

This would give it more visibility and also unrelate the banner from the "similar questions" box, so that it is clear that the problem is explicitly related to OP's question and not a problem within the "similar questions" box or a related notice.

Comment: Completely agree with this request, and would even take it one step further so when this banner is applicable, don't allow to post the question at all, but that's another discussion...

Comment: @Tomerikoo blocking the title could be disastrous. The algorithm isn't very good to begin with - hence it just warns you that similar ones have received down/close votes. It doesn't mean *yours* will. Having to re-write an actually good title because an algorithm thinks it isn't ranks amongst the worst user experiences possible.

Comment: @VLAZ lol I guess you're right... It was just coming from the frustration of seeing so many bad questions, or just the most horrible titles for that matter...

Comment: @Tomerikoo low quality posts will always exist, no matter how much we refine the algorithm... downvotes and flags are the solution to remove visibility from these posts and encourage OP to improve his question. Some initially low quality posts contain very interesting questions, which can be improved later on by editing. If we prevent OP from asking such questions due to a wording issue, this question might never be asked.

Comment: @Tomerikoo SE has much experience with blocking content, for example the [title filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944), it is awesome !!!

Comment: @rene Any pr0blemz with the filter?

Comment: I agree that the filter will not stop the obstinate user. It's just a heads up for well intended askers to rethink their question. anyway, the focus of the question is how do we display this notice, rather than the internals of how the notice is generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We are in early discovery on a project for new user onboarding, helping inexperienced users better learn the rules of the site and how to be successful. (You'll see more on Meta as we get further along.)

We will give this request more thought as part of that project. I've tagged it as status-deferred for now because we need to review this request in the context of the larger project and see if it fits in.